# Alternative needed for annotation ActivationConfigProperty

Tags: jms, jboss6.x, message-driven-bean

I have an MDB on JBoss eap. What I want is to register queues from my java code. All I could find is using ejb-jar.xml if one donot want to use annotation. So is there any way that I can provide destination and destination type from Java code , like my java code will read from properties file for this. Thanks in advance.

```
@MessageDriven(messageListenerInterface=MessageListener.class, 
        activationConfig = {
          @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destinationType", 
                                     propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"),
          @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", 
                                     propertyValue ="test_in")
       }
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the MDB's property values from system properties in annotation itself.

Set annotation to-

```
@ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName = "destination", propertyValue ="${destination.queue.name}")
```

and define `destination.queue.name` as system property in jboss `standalone.xml` -

```
<system-properties>
        <property name="destination.queue.name" value="xx.xx.xx.xx"/>
</system-properties>
```

Make sure that property replacement is enabled in server configuration file and MDB will be deployed with the value provided as system property.